# Top right-hand side s Eclipse icon

Tags: java, eclipse, class, icons

[image]

My Eclipse IDE indicates a Top right-hand side S icon for a java class.
Do you know its meaning ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This indicates that the class / file contains a Spring bean definition, or other Spring elements, and these have been identified by your IDE's Spring tooling.

Comment: Ah yes thank you : an applicationContext.xml was hidden.